# Creating a new dataframe from a dataframe with validation dates and relevant info

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I believe this has been asked but not with these extensions in mind. I have a dataframe with product info and prices based on a start date and end date:

```
    platform    sku start_date  end_date    price
0   A   a   9/5/2019        12/31/9999  19.99
1   A   a   10/28/2017      2/20/2018   24.99
2   A   a   2/21/2018       8/19/2019   29.99
3   A   a   8/20/2019       9/4/2019    24.99
4   A   b   7/22/2019       12/31/9999  34.99
5   A   c   10/17/2019      12/31/9999  19.99
6   A   d   8/31/2019       12/31/9999  34.99
7   A   d   10/19/2017      2/8/2018    29.99
8   A   d   2/9/2018        7/16/2019   34.99
9   A   d   7/17/2019       8/30/2019    39.99
10  B   a   7/17/2019       8/30/2019    39.99
```

I want something like that that would account for not only the sku but the different platforms A and B.

```
         sku    a   b   c   d
start_date              
10/19/17    0       0     0    29.99
10/20/17    0       0     0    29.99
10/21/17    0       0     0    29.99
10/22/17    0       0     0    29.99
10/23/17    0       0     0    29.99
10/24/17    0       0     0    29.99
10/25/17    0       0     0    29.99
10/26/17    0       0     0    29.99
10/27/17    0       0     0    29.99
10/28/17    24.99   0     0    29.99
...
6/26/20     19.99   34.99 19.99 34.99
6/27/20     19.99   34.99 19.99 34.99
6/28/20     19.99   34.99 19.99 34.99
6/29/20     19.99   34.99 19.99 34.99
6/30/20     19.99   34.99 19.99 34.99
7/1/20      19.99   34.99 19.99 34.99
```

Goal: I want to see a table for platform A (and possibly the same with B) with dates ranging from the smallest date in either start or end date to today with each record having the price of that sku at that time with a 0 (not NaN) if it was not in existence yet. I eventually will incorporate this into a processes of continuously updating this new table with this master ledger of skus and valid dates into my database.

I want to perform this with a python script.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.pivot_table(index=['platform','start_date'], columns=['sku'], values='price')

                   sku  a       b       c       d
platform    start_date              
A           10/17/19    NaN     NaN     19.99   NaN
            10/19/17    NaN     NaN     NaN     29.99
             2/21/18    29.99   NaN     NaN     NaN
              2/9/18    NaN     NaN     NaN     34.99
             7/17/19    NaN     NaN     NaN     39.99
             8/20/19    24.99   NaN     NaN     NaN
              9/5/19    19.99   NaN     NaN     NaN
B           10/28/17    24.99   NaN     NaN     NaN
             7/22/19    NaN     34.99   NaN     NaN
             8/31/19    NaN     NaN     NaN     34.99
```

Comment: This is what I got on my attempt with the exact line of code you provided. It is not what I wanted to get out of my original data.

Comment: Why not add an example of your desired output

Comment: Done. Apologies if it was unclear from my paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
df['date'] = df[['start_date','end_date']].min(axis=1)

df.pivot_table('price','date','sku', aggfunc='first').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
sku           a      b      c      d
date                                
10/17/19   0.00   0.00  19.99   0.00
10/19/17   0.00   0.00   0.00  29.99
10/28/17  24.99   0.00   0.00   0.00
12/31/99  19.99  34.99   0.00  34.99
2/21/18   29.99   0.00   0.00   0.00
2/9/18     0.00   0.00   0.00  34.99
7/17/19    0.00   0.00   0.00  39.99
8/20/19   24.99   0.00   0.00   0.00
```